# Finding fields in an object

Tags: java, json

I have an input JSON object which I convert to java vo object using gson api. This is for restful web-services. I have a requirement that the fields in the json are optional. Now how do I handle this in Java, how will I maintain the VO object if am not sure if all the incoming fields will be present or not?
 Say if my actual JSON is { "1":"one","2":"two","3":"three"} this for the POST operation and during a PUT if it comes with {"2":"B"} how will I maintain the VO class. Hope I made myself clear.

Comment: What you tried? Can we see the code? and then eventually we will help you fix it.

Comment: Are the names optional as well? If so try a map else just make the values nullable.

Answer (score 0):

Gson will only attempt to set values for fields that are represented in the JSON input string.
This means, that all fields are optional by default.

Fields that are not present in the JSON string will be null in your object.

Here is an example:

```
ublic class MyClass

    private String value1;
    private String value2;
    private String value3;

    public String getValue1()
    {
        return value1;
    }

    public String getValue2()
    {
        return value2;
    }

    public String getValue3()
    {
        return value3;
    }

    public void setValue1(final String newValue)
    {
        value1 = newValue;
    }

    public void setValue2(final String newValue)
    {
        value2 = newValue;
    }

    public void setValue3(final String newValue)
    {
        value3 = newValue;
    }


public final class Main
{
    private static final String testJson1 = "{ \"value1\":\"first value\"}";
    private static final String testJson2 = "{ \"value2\":\"second value\"}";

    private static void dumpMyClass(final MyClass myClass)
    {
        System.out.println("value1; " + myClass.getValue1());
        System.out.println("value2; " + myClass.getValue2());
        System.out.println("value3; " + myClass.getValue3());
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        MyClass myClass;

        System.out.println("Test1");
        myClass = gson.fromJson(testJson1, MyClass.class);
        dumpMyClass(myClass);

        System.out.println("\nTest2");
        myClass = gson.fromJson(testJson2, MyClass.class);
        dumpMyClass(myClass);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I agree that gson considers every field to be optional but then  while processing the java object how do I handle the optional fields. Say if I want to insert the field values into a table in the database I use the obj.getValue3(), but am doing this with the pre- notion that value3 will be there in the object.

Comment: fields that are not in the JSON will be null.  If you are using Hibernate or MyBatis, this will result in a null column value.  If the column must have a value, then setup a default for the column in the db.